# ArithmeticException not thrown for overflow within 2^32

Tags: java, integer-overflow, arithmeticexception

I know assigning a number greater than `2^32` has a chance to generate an `ArithmeticException` but today while I was programming:

```
int x = 65535
System.out.println(x * x);

Output: -131071
```

So no exception but an unexpected result.

Comment: For the behavior that you were expecting, you can use [Math.multiplyExact(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overflow

Multiplication is **not protected** against overflows.

What you see here is **integer overflow**. If you take the biggest integer `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and add `1` you get the smallest integer `INTEGER.MIN_VALUE`:

```
int value = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(value);  // 2147483647
value++;
System.out.println(value);  // -2147483648
```

The same happens here because

```
65_535 * 65_535 = 4_294_836_225 > 2_147_483_647
```

---

### Range of `int`

In Java `int` is a signed-32-bit value. In particular, it is **not unsigned**.

```
                 |    min-value   |   max-value   |
-----------------|----------------|---------------|
   signed-32-bit |          -2^31 |      2^31 - 1 |
                 | -2_147_483_648 | 2_147_483_647 |
-----------------|----------------|---------------|
 unsigned-32-bit |        2^0 - 1 |      2^32 - 1 |
                 |              0 | 4_294_967_295 |
```

---

### Exception

A multiplication **does not** throw an `ArithmeticException`. To my knowledge this only happens if you divide by `0`, since this should not be possible by definition. Also see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) of the exception.

For a protected multiplication consider using `Math#multiplyExact` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact(int,int))).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing with how many bits the type int which is **32** bits to the numbers which it represent which is between:

```
 -2 147 483 648 <= int <= 2 147 483 647
```

Because it represents also negative numbers and there for can represent only **2^31**

Answer (score 1):

In java, int is primitive signed 32 bit which has

> max value = 2.147.483.647

and

> min value = -2.147.483.648

Result of your multiplication is 4.294.836.225.

Since u use int primitive type, If it `overflows`, it goes back to the `minimum value` and continues from there. If it `underflows`, it goes back to the `maximum value` and continues from there.

If u want to catch an exception, you can use `Math` class or `Integer` class.

```
        try
        {
          int c = Math.multiplyExact(a,b);
        } catch (ArithmeticException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("int is too small, falling back to long.");;
        }
```

Comment: the OP is asking why the overflow exception wasn't raised